# 2nd dropdown not displaying after selecting the value from 2nd dropdown in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am using cascading dropdownlist in asp.net mvc.

When a value is selected from the first dropdown, the list is shown in 2nd dropdown. When I select the value from the 2nd dropdown it shows in the dropdown, but after clicking the submit button it disappears showing "Select from List". Why?

View:

```
<div class="row form-group">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Religion_Id, new { @class = "control-label" })
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon" style="background:white">
                <i class="fa fa-cloud" style="color:#179CDC;"></i>
            </span>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Religion_Id, Model.Religion, "Select From List", new { @class = "form-control select2me", @id = "ddlReligion" })
        </div>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Religion_Id, string.Empty, new { @class = "small text-danger text-uppercase" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Sect_Id, new { @class = "control-label" })
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon" style="background:white">
                <i class="fa fa-cloud" style="color:#179CDC;"></i>
            </span>
            <div id="Sects">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Sect_Id, new List<SelectListItem>(), "Select Form List", new { @class = "form-control select2me", @id = "ddlSect" })
            </div>
        </div>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Sect_Id, string.Empty, new { @class = "small text-danger text-uppercase" })
    </div>
</div>

<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    loadSect();
});

var loadSect = function (flag) {
    if ("undefined" == typeof (flag)) {
        flag = true;
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: '@Url.Action("GetSects", "MyProfile", new { area = "Candidate" })',
        data: { religionId: $('#ddlReligion').val() },
        datatype: "json",
        traditional: true,
        success: function (data) {
            var district = "<select id='ddlSect' class='form-control text-uppercase select2me' name='Sect_Id'>";
            district = district + '<option value="">Select From List</option>';
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                district = district + '<option value=' + data[i].Value + '>' + data[i].Text + '</option>';
            }
            district = district + '</select>';
            $('#Sects').html(district);

            if (flag) {
                setOption($('#Sects select')[0], $('#HSPEC_ID').val())
            }


            if (jQuery().select2) {
                $('#Sects .select2me').select2({
                    placeholder: "Select an option",
                    allowClear: true
                });
            }
        }
    });
};


$('#ddlReligion').change(function () {
    loadSect(false);
});

function setOption(selectElement, value) {
    var options = selectElement.options;
    for (var i = 0, optionsLength = options.length; i < optionsLength; i++) {
        if (options[i].value == value) {
            selectElement.selectedIndex = i;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> **You are not doing a ajax submit.** OR **Your are not setting the value of second drop down back after post**

In your code, I don't see any ajax submit after you choose the second drop dwn and hit submit. So the problem is you are posting this form to controller and then the controller is returning the view back with the same posted data. Now in the Razor syntax for the second drop down you are using

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Sect_Id, new List<SelectListItem>(), "Select Form List", new { @class = "form-control select2me", @id = "ddlSect" })
```

Here you can see you are setting the value of second drop down by empty list `new List<SelectListItem>()` and that is why the second drop down is empty.

**Solution**

1. Either use AJAX submit for your form. So that your UI remains unchanged.
2. Change your Razor syntax to this

   `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Sect_Id, Model.District, "Select Form List", new { @class = "form-control select2me", @id = "ddlSect" })`

So add a additional property called `Districts` and initially set this `Model.District` to be `new List<SelectListItem>()` and then in your form post method you just pass back the data as received and it will be rendered properly after submit.

Comment: dropdownlist has the list of sects... i can also select the value from 2nd dropdown but after selecting and clicking the submit button it doesn.t display anything

Comment: @SecretStar I have explained the reason for why it does not display anything.